# Create a new array on a combination of arrays based on a key in the arrays javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays as input (array1 & array2) for which I want to check if there is a match on id.
If there is a match they should be included in a new array called result.

```
array1 = [
{ x_id:6711230070958, id:279482 },
{ x_id:6770878283950, id:213 },
{ x_id:6753301168302, id:330120 }
];
    
array2 = [
{ id: 279482, stock: 9 }, 
{ id: 31231, stock: 2 }, 
{ id: 330120, stock: 2 }
];

result [
{ x_id:6711230070958, id: 279482, stock: 9 },
{ x_id:6753301168302, id: 330120, stock: 2 }
]
```

For finding the matches I tried using a filter with includes.
Anybody some thoughts on this?

Comment: Most of the thoughts I have on this come from answers on this site. Perhaps you could could [edit] your question to show what research you've done and any attempts you've made based on that research?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
array1 = [
    { x_id:6711230070958, id:279482 },
    { x_id:6770878283950, id:213 },
    { x_id:6753301168302, id:330120 }
];
    
array2 = [
    { id: 279482, stock: 9 }, 
    { id: 31231, stock: 2 }, 
    { id: 330120, stock: 2 }
];


let arr3 = array1.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, array2[i]));

console.log(arr3)
```

Comment: This gives me three results where I would like to have 2 :) But thanks for the fast response.

Comment: That is because the id match condition is not added here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
array1 = [
{ x_id:6711230070958, id:279482 },
{ x_id:6770878283950, id:213 },
{ x_id:6753301168302, id:330120 }
];
    
array2 = [
{ id: 279482, stock: 9 }, 
{ id: 31231, stock: 2 }, 
{ id: 330120, stock: 2 }
];

result = [];

array1.forEach(ele=> {
  let match = array2.find(e => e.id == ele.id);
  if(match)
     result.push(Object.assign({}, ele, match))
})
```

Comment: Whenever you write a `push` in a `forEach`, you can probably use `map`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey This is a conditional push. We will end up having undefined entries in array we use map (unless we use filter again after map).